# When using ".Get(0)" on an empty list, I get an out of bounds exception and not null?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

So in my homework assignment, for my error checking testing stuff I do a get on a `List<SomeObject>` and I get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I solve it by using a check on `.isEmpty` but what I would like to know why doesn't:

```
boolean b = myList.Get(0) != null;
```

work?

When I debug the application and look at `myList` I see 9 entries of `null`. I can see it as being size `0` though, so that's probably why? It's size `0`, so when I try to get an entry it doesn't exist?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: @RyanGates: either java or C# doesn't matter cus is valid java and C# is the copy

Comment: @DudeBro: In what way is this valid Java? The method would be `get`, not `Get` - and it probably wouldn't use property names like that... (The OP has said it's Java, which just shows that he hasn't posted the actual code...)

Comment: In future, please post *real* code, and indicate the language in the question. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: @Jon Skeet, it is java i am rigtht see op accepted answer comment

Comment: @DudeBro: Please read my comment - I specifically *said* that the OP had said it was Java. I said it wasn't *valid* Java, assuming that the OP is using a normal list implementation. (Fundamentally, this is a badly written question, basically.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tag it as java it wasnt there before

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it is Java:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.get(0);
```

will cause

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at HelloWorldTester.main(HelloWorldTester.java:7)
```

The reason is actually on the source code. rangecheck is probably checking if what you are trying to get is lower than the size of the list. If it is higher 
then

```
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
```

Answer (score 2):

Working as designed. I don't understand why you expect to be able to get anything, even `null`, from an empty `List`. You can't.

Comment: Working as designed yes, but the `null` behaviour could be useful. The choice was arbitrary.